# Pulling a Windows Image for Docker on Windows Server 2019 has OS compatibility issues

Tags: docker, nano-server, server-core, windows-server-2019

I have recently tried to pull and run a Docker image (that worked on Windows 10) on a Windows Server 2019 instance which failed with the following error message:

> The container operating system does not match the host operating system.

I've tried it on the latest version of `Windows Server Core` and `Nano Server` from the normal `microsoft/windowsservercore` and `microsoft/nanoserver` repositories.

I don't understand because those are Windows Kernels running on a Windows Operating System.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue pulling the image `microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer` in a Windows Server 2019 host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the feedback given on [this github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/960) you have to pull the repository from Microsoft's new Container Registry (mcr.microsoft.com) for a specific version (1809). This version is compatible with Windows Server 2019.

> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
>
> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809

Also beware that `nanoserver` no longer has Power-Shell in its base image.

As for why this is happening, I am not sure. Would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on the subject.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't keep the interface between User mode (a bit like glibc) and the NT kernel compatible across versions. This means that the docker (container) virtualisation is sitting on an unstable environment and so is only guaranteed to work when the guest and host have *exactly* the same windows version. In the real world it usually works if the versions are pretty close and will only throw that error if the versions are far enough apart that it's known to break. Note: Linux has similar issues, however, the time is more like 10 years by default, with flags extending this over 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

This error appears because Windows 10 and Windows Server have different Isolation Modes: Hyper-V Isolation for Win 10 and Process Isolation for Win Server. You can find more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210212185057/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container)

Comment: Whereas it's useful to know about the different isolation modes, it does not seem to be the cause of this error. See https://support.codefresh.io/hc/en-us/articles/360016063140-Windows-The-container-operating-system-does-not-match-the-host-operating-system-

Comment: Isolation mode is the workaround for this issue. When you have "HyperV" isolation docker uses a full VM to run a windows container on a Windows host.