# failed to create shim task: hcs::CreateComputeSystem xx: container operating system does not match the host operating system:unknown

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker-compose, azure-aks

I am new to docker and AKS. I am using Docker Desktop for windows to containerize the legacy asp.net Framework 4.6.2 application. I then pushed the image to ACR. When i try to create a pod in windows container using the image, it ended up with error "CrashLoopBackOff". Below are the details

**My Windows Version:**
[Windows Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIwSL.png)

**AKS Windows Nodepoll version:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1OWs.png)

**Docker Desktop Version:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLmga.png)

**Docker Container Image version:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFiV.png)

**yaml file i used:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNJOS.png)

**The Dockerfile generated in visual studio 2022 when adding docker support:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz7hx.png)

**Pod Error File:**

```
C:\Users\RAslam>kubectl describe pod sample
E1103 12:31:00.996225   38536 describe.go:616] Unable to construct reference to '&core.Pod{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"sample-5f67b5d8c9-pz4mk", GenerateName:"sample-5f67b5d8c9-", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"0f982ec0-656d-48e0-a82e-6698ca5e98d6", ResourceVersion:"22916294", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:63834591617, loc:(*time.Location)(0x254cf00)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"app":"sample", "pod-template-hash":"5f67b5d8c9"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference{v1.OwnerReference{APIVersion:"apps/v1", Kind:"ReplicaSet", Name:"sample-5f67b5d8c9", UID:"ffc754ab-4632-4147-b805-69860eb9f4c0", Controller:(*bool)(0xc0427ee757), BlockOwnerDeletion:(*bool)(0xc0427ee758)}}, Initializers:(*v1.Initializers)(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:""}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume{core.Volume{Name:"kube-api-access-qlswg", VolumeSource:core.VolumeSource{HostPath:(*core.HostPathVolumeSource)(nil), EmptyDir:(*core.EmptyDirVolumeSource)(nil), GCEPersistentDisk:(*core.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)(nil), AWSElasticBlockStore:(*core.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)(nil), GitRepo:(*core.GitRepoVolumeSource)(nil), Secret:(*core.SecretVolumeSource)(nil), NFS:(*core.NFSVolumeSource)(nil), ISCSI:(*core.ISCSIVolumeSource)(nil), Glusterfs:(*core.GlusterfsVolumeSource)(nil), PersistentVolumeClaim:(*core.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource)(nil), RBD:(*core.RBDVolumeSource)(nil), Quobyte:(*core.QuobyteVolumeSource)(nil), FlexVolume:(*core.FlexVolumeSource)(nil), Cinder:(*core.CinderVolumeSource)(nil), CephFS:(*core.CephFSVolumeSource)(nil), Flocker:(*core.FlockerVolumeSource)(nil), DownwardAPI:(*core.DownwardAPIVolumeSource)(nil), FC:(*core.FCVolumeSource)(nil), AzureFile:(*core.AzureFileVolumeSource)(nil), ConfigMap:(*core.ConfigMapVolumeSource)(nil), VsphereVolume:(*core.VsphereVirtualDiskVolumeSource)(nil), AzureDisk:(*core.AzureDiskVolumeSource)(nil), PhotonPersistentDisk:(*core.PhotonPersistentDiskVolumeSource)(nil), Projected:(*core.ProjectedVolumeSource)(0xc042c04bc0), PortworxVolume:(*core.PortworxVolumeSource)(nil), ScaleIO:(*core.ScaleIOVolumeSource)(nil), StorageOS:(*core.StorageOSVolumeSource)(nil)}}}, InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"sample", Image:"prdeacdcacrdynamics.azurecr.io/devopsguru:dev", Command:[]string(nil), Args:[]string(nil), WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort{core.ContainerPort{Name:"", HostPort:0, ContainerPort:80, Protocol:"TCP", HostIP:""}}, EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar(nil), Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount{core.VolumeMount{Name:"kube-api-access-qlswg", ReadOnly:true, MountPath:"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount", SubPath:"", MountPropagation:(*core.MountPropagationMode)(nil)}}, VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"IfNotPresent", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, RestartPolicy:"Always", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc0427eeb48), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string{"kubernetes.io/os":"windows"}, ServiceAccountName:"default", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"aksnpwin1000000", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc0421ed490), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration{core.Toleration{Key:"node.kubernetes.io/not-ready", Operator:"Exists", Value:"", Effect:"NoExecute", TolerationSeconds:(*int64)(0xc0427eec10)}, core.Toleration{Key:"node.kubernetes.io/unreachable", Operator:"Exists", Value:"", Effect:"NoExecute", TolerationSeconds:(*int64)(0xc0427eec30)}}, HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(0xc0427eec40), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil)}, Status:core.PodStatus{Phase:"Running", Conditions:[]core.PodCondition{core.PodCondition{Type:"Initialized", Status:"True", LastProbeTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, LastTransitionTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:63834591617, loc:(*time.Location)(0x254cf00)}}, Reason:"", Message:""}, core.PodCondition{Type:"Ready", Status:"False", LastProbeTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, LastTransitionTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:63834591617, loc:(*time.Location)(0x254cf00)}}, Reason:"ContainersNotReady", Message:"containers with unready status: [sample]"}, core.PodCondition{Type:"ContainersReady", Status:"False", LastProbeTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, LastTransitionTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:63834591617, loc:(*time.Location)(0x254cf00)}}, Reason:"ContainersNotReady", Message:"containers with unready status: [sample]"}, core.PodCondition{Type:"PodScheduled", Status:"True", LastProbeTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, LastTransitionTime:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:63834591617, loc:(*time.Location)(0x254cf00)}}, Reason:"", Message:""}}, Message:"", Reason:"", NominatedNodeName:"", HostIP:"172.18.16.249", PodIP:"172.18.17.13", StartTime:(*v1.Time)(0xc042c04b40), QOSClass:"BestEffort", InitContainerStatuses:[]core.ContainerStatus(nil), ContainerStatuses:[]core.ContainerStatus{core.ContainerStatus{Name:"sample", State:core.ContainerState{Waiting:(*core.ContainerStateWaiting)(0xc042c04b80), Running:(*core.ContainerStateRunning)(nil), Terminated:(*core.ContainerStateTerminated)(nil)}, LastTerminationState:core.ContainerState{Waiting:(*core.ContainerStateWaiting)(nil), Running:(*core.ContainerStateRunning)(nil), Terminated:(*core.ContainerStateTerminated)(0xc0421ed420)}, Ready:false, RestartCount:2, Image:"prdeacdcacrdynamics.azurecr.io/devopsguru:dev", ImageID:"prdeacdcacrdynamics.azurecr.io/devopsguru@sha256:c2356743faf0a5dad7cbc42fdc963a355a88e6569c2dfbe46dae96c4272fe38b", ContainerID:"containerd://eee0b5364f67c17037b92262fcecd474a1bdea1d7739516a478b1e9e6a669676"}}}}': selfLink was empty, can't make reference
Name:               sample-5f67b5d8c9-pz4mk
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               aksnpwin1000000/172.18.16.249
Start Time:         Fri, 03 Nov 2023 12:30:17 +0530
Labels:             app=sample
                    pod-template-hash=5f67b5d8c9
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.18.17.13
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/sample-5f67b5d8c9
Containers:
  sample:
    Container ID:   containerd://eee0b5364f67c17037b92262fcecd474a1bdea1d7739516a478b1e9e6a669676
    Image:          prdeacdcacrdynamics.azurecr.io/devopsguru:dev
    Image ID:       prdeacdcacrdynamics.azurecr.io/devopsguru@sha256:c2356743faf0a5dad7cbc42fdc963a355a88e6569c2dfbe46dae96c4272fe38b    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       RunContainerError
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       StartError
      Message:      failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: hcs::CreateComputeSystem eee0b5364f67c17037b92262fcecd474a1bdea1d7739516a478b1e9e6a669676: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.: unknown
      Exit Code:    128
      Started:      Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 +0530
      Finished:     Fri, 03 Nov 2023 12:30:51 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-qlswg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-qlswg:
  <unknown>
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=windows
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
```

what am i missing here? if i want to change base image, how should i do it? How to rebuild my image. should i manually edit in visual studio. I visited the link - https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet. But still not clear how to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @Reyah, have you been able to fix that issue? I am facing the similar one. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

AKS by default creates a Linux nodepool, inorder to run Windows containers, you need to create a new Windows nodepool. (example name in my case- npwin)
[image]
Please note, AKS requires Windows Server containers to be based on images of Windows Server 2019 or greater. I am using windows server 2022.
[image]
and in order run an AKS cluster that supports node pools for Windows Server containers, your cluster needs to use a network policy that uses [Azure CNI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-container-networking/blob/master/docs/cni.md)
[image]

Once your cluster is ready, verify the nodes

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces=true

kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

and deploy your .Net yaml file. It should work without throwing the above error message.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample
  labels:
    app: sample
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: sample
      labels:
        app: sample
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: sample
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 800M
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: sample

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: sample
```

`kubectl apply -f sample.yaml`

[image]

`kubectl get pods`

[image]

Reference Documents:

[Compatible Windows Container Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022,windows-11)

[failed to create shim task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167643/unable-to-create-container-in-windows-node)
[Windows Container on AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/quick-windows-container-deploy-cli?tabs=add-windows-server-2019-node-pool)

[Container OS does not match host OS](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/issues/751)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637682/pulling-a-windows-image-for-docker-on-windows-server-2019-has-os-compatibility-i)